# PLSQL SUM values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question that shares similarities with a previously asked inquiry  [Oracle SQL sum up values till another value is reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37434686/oracle-sql-sum-up-values-till-another-value-is-reached) , but unfortunately, it doesn't provide a complete solution to my current issue. Therefore, I would appreciate your assistance in formulating a response to my specific situation. Thank you in advance for your time and support.

Table that I have:

```
I_ID| number        | number_2       |nb1 | id2 |nb2| co1  | co2  | co3  | co4  | co5  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | 7002940263    | OP000093652280 |1   |8    |1  |   1  |4     |  0.05| ga1  |      |        
3   | 7002940263    | OP000044486481 |1   |8    |2  |   1  |4     |  0.05| ga1  |      |
4   | 7002940263    | OP000004726042 |1   |8    |3  |   1  |4     |  0.05| ga1  |      |
5   | 7002940263    | OP000014726070 |1   |8    |4  |   1  |4     |  0.05| ga1  |      |
6   | 7002949263    | OP007034975456 |1   |8    |5  |   1  |4     |  0.05| ga1  |      | 
7   | 5002949262    | OP007004975465 |1   |1    |1  |0.02  |0.1   |  0.05| ga1  |  ga2 |
8   | 5002949262    | OP040004975467 |1   |1    |2  |0.02  |0.1   |  0.05| ga1  |  ga2 |
9   | 5002949262    | OP005004975469 |0,6 |1    |2.6|0.02  |0.1   |  0.05| ga1  |  ga2 |
10  | 5002949262    | OP000074975472 |1   |1    |3.6|0.02  |0.1   |  0.05| ga1  |  ga2 |
11  | 5002949262    | OP009095237583 |1   |1    |4.6|0.02  |0.1   |  0.05| ga1  |  ga2 |
```

As you can see in the **nb2** column I have already applied the command `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` where the summation was done by column **nb1**

The result I am trying to get:

```
I_ID| number        | number_2       |nb1 | id2 |nb2| co1 | co2| co3  | co4  | co5  |fin|fin2|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | 7002940263    | OP000093652280 |1   |1    |1  |   1  |4  |  0.01| ga1  |      |co1|1   |
3   | 7002940263    | OP000044486481 |1   |1    |2  |   1  |4  |  0.01| ga1  |      |co2|4   |
4   | 7002940263    | OP000004726042 |1   |1    |3  |   1  |4  |  0.01| ga1  |      |co3|4   |
5   | 7002940263    | OP000014726070 |1   |1    |4  |   1  |4  |  0.01| ga1  |      |co4|4   |
6   | 7002949263    | OP007034975456 |1   |1    |5  |   1  |4  |  0.01| ga1  |      |co4|4   |
7   | 5002949262    | OP007004975465 |1   |8    |1  | 0.02 |0.1|  0.05| ga1  |  ga2 |co1|0.02|
8   | 5002949262    | OP040004975467 |1   |8    |2  | 0.02 |0.1|  0.05| ga1  |  ga2 |co2|0.1 |
9   | 5002949262    | OP005004975469 |0.6 |8    |2.6| 0.02 |0.1|  0.05| ga1  |  ga2 |co3|0.05|
10  | 5002949262    | OP000074975472 |1   |8    |3.6| 0.02 |0.1|  0.05| ga1  |  ga2 |co5|ga1 |
11  | 5002949262    | OP009095237583 |1   |8    |4.6| 0.02 |0.1|  0.05| ga1  |  ga2 |co5|ga2 |
```

If there is a possibility, I would like to ask you to help me assign the columns **co1**, **co2**,**co3**, **co4**, **co5** . This data in columns should be assigned by column **nb1**. If the sum in the column **nb1** is above the number  **co1**, **co2**,**co3** in the columns then the columns are assigned **co4**, **co5**. It is possible that, for example, the column **co1** will exceed the amount (sum) in the value column **nb1**, then only it will be allocated until it covers **nb1**.

One solution would be to perhaps sum the column values **nb1** up to the value column **co1** and then further sum up to the value at column **co2** and so on. How to achieve such a result?

The code that I am thinking of:

```
   select table1.I_ID,table1.number  ,table1.number_2,table1.nb1,table1.id2,table1.nb2 ,
    
    ( CASE WHEN (tabele1.co1) >= (tabele1.nb2)  THEN to_char('co1') 
     WHEN(tabele1.co2)  >= (tabele1.nb2)  THEN  to_char('co2')
       WHEN (tabele1.co3)  >= (tabele1.nb2)  THEN to_char('co3' )
                when  (tabele1.co4) <> to_char(0) and table.id2 in (1) then to_char('co4')
                  else  to_char(case when (tabele1.co5) is not null and table.id2 in (8) then to_char('co5') end)              
           END
            )fin,
    
    ( CASE WHEN (tabele1.co1)  >= m.sg2  THEN table1.co1 
     WHEN (tabele1.co2) >= m.sg2  THEN table1.co2
       WHEN (tabele1.co3)  >= m.sg2  THEN table1.co3
                when  (tabele1.co4) <> 0 and table.id2 in (8) then 0
                  else  to_number(case when (tabele1.co5) is not null then 0
                   end)
                                  
           END
            ) fin2         
    from 
    (select np.*,  sum(np.sg) OVER( PARTITION BY table1.number
    ORDER BY table1.number, table1.nb1 desc
            ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
     ) nb2, 
    from table1
```

Comment: If you are using Oracle SQL, what was your reason for using the [tag:mysql] tag on your question?

Comment: Please provide your SQL itself, we can only guess how you are generating some of those columns. Also please elaborate on the logic: `"If the sum in the column nb1 is above the number co1, co2,co3 in the columns then the columns are assigned co4, co5"`. THe values you have in co1,co2,co3 are always lower than `nb2` so it's unclear what the conditional logic intended is. And what is meant by "the columns are assigned co4, co5" ?

Comment: Also PL/SQL is the programming language, it doesn't have SUM.

Comment: Thank you @Paul W . The values at co1, co2, co3 can be also higher. I will try to provide code.